# Different size tyre has arrived than ordered

Tags: tire, size

I normally get my local bike shop to change my tyres but due to the COVID19 Pandemic they are not open.
I have a Ridgeback Terrain 2 that came fitted with 27.5 x 2.10 tyres
I ordered that size of tyre but the one that has just arrived is in fact 27.5 x 2.25. I have no idea what this all means and looking up various articles on the internet has just left me even more confused.
Therefore I thought I would ask people on here as I am sure someone will quickly be able to tell me whether or not I can put this tyre on my bike or if I need the supplier to replace it with the size I actually ordered.
Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: The widths differ by 0.15 inches -- less than a quarter of an inch.  The only reason this tire would not fit would be if the bike frame were so narrow that it rubbed.  But that would be very unusual, if the 2.10 tires are original with the bike.

Comment: In most countries you can return mail order items no questions asked. Even if you can't, delivering the wrong item is a good reason.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I had kinda hoped as Daniel says that I will be ok. The 2.10 tyres did come with the bike. I have of course emailed Amazon and will see what they say but anything that simplifies things whilst we all go through this crazy time is good.

Comment: First number is a nominal tire diameter and really means you have ISO 584mm rims (common on MTBs, along with '29" ' ISO 622mm). Second number is nominal tire width in inches. See https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks - those exact dimensions of tires gave me a problem. 2.25 rubbed the chain stay.  2.10 in the same model tire and is good.

Comment: @mattnz - Yep, depends on the bike.  With the bike in front of you and the narrower tire on it you can check clearances, and see if it looks like enough.  (You do need to allow for the fact that there is a degree of variation in actual width between tire manufacturers/styles for a stated width, though.)

Comment: @mattnz in that case, for the short term, I'd choose to move the half-worn original front to the rear, and install one of the larger front tyres there if it fits.   And email the supplier saying what's wrong now, so theres a dated record.  BUT based on the current circumstances, there's little reason to ride anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion Criggie a good idea. I'm a key healthcare worker and so need my bike to get to work and I'm permitted to travel at present due to my work role